# php merge json arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

array 1:

```
[
{"PlayerID":"17794204","userName":"Vandiel","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"1476253231000"},
{"PlayerID":"21532584","userName":"Mayland","castleCount":"1","NotUpd":"0"},
{"PlayerID":"21539896","userName":"Dana","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"0"}
]
```

array 2:

```
[
{"PlayerID":"17794204","Trouble":"2"},
{"PlayerID":"21532584","Trouble":"0"},
{"PlayerID":"21539896","Trouble":"0"}
]
```

Those both were pulled from mySQL database using fetch_assoc_all()

I tried merge_array, merge_array_recursive, json_decode(xx,true) and all kinds of things I could think on top of my head and elsewhere via google.  I'm looking for a way to merge both array1, array2 into something like:

```
[
{"PlayerID":"17794204","userName":"Vandiel","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"1476253231000","Trouble":"2"},
{"PlayerID":"21532584","userName":"Mayland","castleCount":"1","NotUpd":"0","Trouble":"0"},
{"PlayerID":"21539896","userName":"Dana","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"0","Trouble":"0"}
]
```

PlayerID are always unique.  Hope to hear what insight I could do to merge those 2 arrays (array1,array2)

(Additonal/Edit)
For those wondering what's mySQL looks like (I couldn't wrap my head around on JOIN statement):

```
$mSQL = 'SELECT nPlayer.PlayerID,userName,castleCount,IF(LastUpdate < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 3720),LastUpdate*1000,0) NotUpd';
$mSQL .= ' FROM nPlayer';
$mSQL .= ' LEFT JOIN nMains ON nMains.mID = nPlayer.mID';
$mSQL .= ' WHERE nMains.Main = "'.$M.'"  AND nMains.Pass = "'.md5($P).'" AND nMains.Server = "'.$S.'"';
$mSQL .= ' ORDER BY nPlayer.PlayerID';

$mSQL = 'SELECT nCity.PlayerID,SUM(IF(Wartown > 0,1,0))+SUM(IF(support < 100,1,0))) Trouble';
$mSQL .= ' FROM nCity';
$mSQL .= ' INNER JOIN nPlayer ON nPlayer.PlayerID = nCity.PlayerID AND nPlayer.mID = nCity.mID';
$mSQL .= ' INNER JOIN nMains ON nMains.mID = nPlayer.mID';
$mSQL .= ' WHERE nMains.Main = "'.$M.'"  AND nMains.Pass = "'.md5($P).'" AND nMains.Server = "'.$S.'"';
$mSQL .= ' GROUP BY nCity.PlayerID';
```

Comment: You better use MYSQL JOIN Operation in query when you pulled the data

Comment: I tried mySQL JOIN on that, couldn't wrap my head around on those because its from 2 different tables but one query requires GROUP BY when other doesn't.

Comment: edited above to include mySQL

Comment: In the 2nd query you can try with nCity.PlayerID, nPlayer.userName, nPlayer.castleCount, .....

Comment: @sgkdnay. I have provided with the explanations about the output you required and has provided with the code too. Share thoughts and let me know if you face any hindrance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Detailed Explanation

You can join the JSON array based on the key value that you obtain provided you have to give under which key you have to join the `json_array()`.

I am going to consider the `json_objects` as follows based on the PHP code.

```
<?php
$array1 = '[
{"PlayerID":"17794204","userName":"Vandiel","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"1476253231000"},
{"PlayerID":"21532584","userName":"Mayland","castleCount":"1","NotUpd":"0"},
{"PlayerID":"21539896","userName":"Dana","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"0"}
]';
$array2 = '[
{"PlayerID":"17794204","Trouble":"2"},
{"PlayerID":"21532584","Trouble":"0"},
{"PlayerID":"21539896","Trouble":"0"}
]';
?>
```

Hence inorder to merget the json_objects we have to first use `json_decode()` for the both the arrays that we have obtained.

```
$decode_one = json_decode($array1,TRUE);
$decode_two = json_decode($array2,TRUE);
```

Hence the output for the `json_decoded()` string will be as follows.

First Decoded String:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [PlayerID] => 17794204 [userName] => Vandiel [castleCount] => 9 [NotUpd] => 1476253231000 ) [1] => Array ( [PlayerID] => 21532584 [userName] => Mayland [castleCount] => 1 [NotUpd] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [PlayerID] => 21539896 [userName] => Dana [castleCount] => 9 [NotUpd] => 0 ) )
```

Second Decoded String:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [PlayerID] => 17794204 [Trouble] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [PlayerID] => 21532584 [Trouble] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [PlayerID] => 21539896 [Trouble] => 0 ) )
```

> After that we have to `merge the two arrays` that we have obtained based on the `key` that is `unique` for us.

Hence the function for the code is as follows.

I have considered the **PlayerID** as the **UNIQUE** Parameter and has combined the array.

```
function merge_json_decoded_arrays($decode_one,$decode_two) {
    $data = array();
    $arrayAB = array_merge($decode_one,$decode_two);
    foreach ($arrayAB as $value) {
      $id = $value['PlayerID'];
      if (!isset($data[$id])) {
        $data[$id] = array();
      }
      $data[$id] = array_merge($data[$id],$value);
    }
    return $data;
  }
```

You need to call the function like this from the code where you need to perform the `array_merge()` operations.

```
$merged_array = merge_json_decoded_arrays($decode_one,$decode_two);
```

Finally the full code appears like this with the setup.

**Full Code:**

```
<?php
$array1 = '[
{"PlayerID":"17794204","userName":"Vandiel","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"1476253231000"},
{"PlayerID":"21532584","userName":"Mayland","castleCount":"1","NotUpd":"0"},
{"PlayerID":"21539896","userName":"Dana","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"0"}
]';
$array2 = '[
{"PlayerID":"17794204","Trouble":"2"},
{"PlayerID":"21532584","Trouble":"0"},
{"PlayerID":"21539896","Trouble":"0"}
]';

$decode_one = json_decode($array1,TRUE);
$decode_two = json_decode($array2,TRUE);

function merge_json_decoded_arrays($decode_one,$decode_two) {
    $data = array();
    $arrayAB = array_merge($decode_one,$decode_two);
    foreach ($arrayAB as $value) {
      $id = $value['PlayerID'];
      if (!isset($data[$id])) {
        $data[$id] = array();
      }
      $data[$id] = array_merge($data[$id],$value);
    }
    return $data;
  }
$merged_array = merge_json_decoded_arrays($decode_one,$decode_two);
?>
```

In order to view the merged array you need to `print_r()` the array and view it.

**Array Output Code:**

```
print_r($merged_array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [17794204] => Array ( [PlayerID] => 17794204 [userName] => Vandiel [castleCount] => 9 [NotUpd] => 1476253231000 [Trouble] => 2 ) [21532584] => Array ( [PlayerID] => 21532584 [userName] => Mayland [castleCount] => 1 [NotUpd] => 0 [Trouble] => 0 ) [21539896] => Array ( [PlayerID] => 21539896 [userName] => Dana [castleCount] => 9 [NotUpd] => 0 [Trouble] => 0 ) )
```

If you need it as the JSON output you have to `json_encode()` the obtained `array()` and perform the operations.

> **Note:** It takes the `unique ID` as the `array key` for each row that is been generated.

**JSON Output Code:**

```
print_r(json_ecode($merged_array));
```

**Output:**

```
{"17794204":{"PlayerID":"17794204","userName":"Vandiel","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"1476253231000","Trouble":"2"},"21532584":{"PlayerID":"21532584","userName":"Mayland","castleCount":"1","NotUpd":"0","Trouble":"0"},"21539896":{"PlayerID":"21539896","userName":"Dana","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"0","Trouble":"0"}}
```

### Fastest Execution Method will take up this way

You need to decode the json_strings and then you have to llop both of them through the `foreach()` and then combine with the `array()` that you need to join with it.

```
$decode_one = json_decode($array1,TRUE);
$decode_two = json_decode($array2,TRUE);
foreach ($decode_one as $key => $first_value) {
    foreach ($decode_two as $key_two => $second_value) {
        if($first_value['PlayerID']==$second_value['PlayerID'])
        { $decode_one[$key]['Trouble'] = $second_value['Trouble'];//Here if the key exists it will join the Trouble with the First decoded array }
        else {}
    }
}
$combined_output = json_encode($decode_one); //This will return the output in json format.
```

**Output:**

```
[{"PlayerID":"17794204","userName":"Vandiel","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"1476253231000","Trouble":"2"},{"PlayerID":"21532584","userName":"Mayland","castleCount":"1","NotUpd":"0","Trouble":"0"},{"PlayerID":"21539896","userName":"Dana","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"0","Trouble":"0"}]
```

Comment: This method works well.  Until one person mentioned JOIN, i just smack my head to the table and didn't realized the simplify of it.  Most definitely will be useful for additonal work I plan to do with other JSONs

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `json1` and `json2` are your two JSON strings, **the solution** to merge these two JSON strings would be like this:

- First decode these two JSON strings using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to get `$decodedArray1` and `$decodedArray2` arrays.
- Run two nested `foreach` loops to merge `$decodedArray2` into `$decodedArray1` array.
- Finally, apply [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function on `$decodedArray1` array to get the resultant JSON string.

Here's the code:

```
$decodedArray1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$decodedArray2 = json_decode($json2, true);

foreach($decodedArray1 as $key => $array1){
    foreach($decodedArray2 as $array2){
        if($array1['PlayerID'] == $array2['PlayerID']){
            $decodedArray1[$key]['Trouble'] = $array2['Trouble'];
        }
    }
}

$resultantJson = json_encode($decodedArray1);
```

Here's the [**live demo**](https://eval.in/660911)

Answer (score 0):

There is no function in PHP that does what you want. If you look around the usual suspect frameworks you'll find they use a merge functionality like the following:

```
/**
 * @param array $array
 * @param array $other
 *
 * @return array
 */
function _array_merge(array $array, array $other)
{
    foreach ($other as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($array[$key]) || array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            if (is_int($key)) {
                $array[] = $value;
            } elseif (is_array($value) && is_array($array[$key])) {
                $array[$key] = _array_merge($array[$key], $value);
            } else {
                $array[$key] = $value;
            }
        } else {
            $array[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

With the above you can `json_decode()` each element then merge them and then `json_encode()` the result.

For completeness, here is a test case for the above merge function:

```
<?php

class ArrayMergeTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testMerge(array $expected, array $a, array $b)
    {
        $this->assertSame($expected, _array_merge($a, $b));
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function provideMerge()
    {
        return array(
            'should-preserve-integer-keys' => array(
                array(
                    2 => array('a', 'b', 'c'),
                    3 => array('d', 'e', 'f'),
                ),
                array(2 => array('a', 'b', 'c')),
                array(2 => array('d', 'e', 'f')),
            ),
            'should-merge-when-no-existing-key' => array(
                array(
                    'a' => array('b', 'c'),
                    'd' => array('e', 'f'),
                ),
                array('a' => array('b', 'c')),
                array('d' => array('e', 'f')),
            ),
            'should-overwrite-key-when-not-array' => array(
                array('a' => 'b'),
                array('a' => 'foo'),
                array('a' => 'b'),
            ),
            'should-merge-recursive' => array(
                array('a' => array(0 => 'b', 1 => 'c')),
                array('a' => array('b')),
                array('a' => array('c')),
            ),
            'should-replace-string-keys' => array(
                array('foo' => 'baz', 'bar' => 'bat'),
                array('foo' => 'bar', 'bar' => array()),
                array('foo' => 'baz', 'bar' => 'bat'),
            ),
            'should-merge-nested' => array(
                array('a' => array('b' => array('baz', 'bat'))),
                array('a' => array('b' => array('baz'))),
                array('a' => array('b' => array('bat'))),
            ),
            'should-merge-simple-keys' => array(
                array('a' => 'a_val', 'b' => 'b_val'),
                array('a' => 'a_val'),
                array('b' => 'b_val'),
            ),

            // Ensure documentation examples work

            'doc_example_1' => array(
                array(42 => 'x', 43 => 'y'),
                array(42 => 'x'),
                array(42 => 'y'),
            ),

            'doc_example_2_a' => array(
                array('x' => 'b'),
                array('x' => 'a'),
                array('x' => 'b'),
            ),
            'doc_example_2_b' => array(
                array('x' => 'b'),
                array('x' => array('a')),
                array('x' => 'b'),
            ),
            'doc_example_2_c' => array(
                array('x' => array('b')),
                array('x' => 'a'),
                array('x' => array('b')),
            ),
            'doc_example_2_d' => array(
                array('x' => array('a', 'b')),
                array('x' => array('a')),
                array('x' => array('b')),
            ),
            'merge-integer-and-string-keys' => array(
                array(
                    0 => 'foo',
                    3 => 'bar',
                    'baz' => 'baz',
                    4 => array(
                        'a',
                        1 => 'b',
                        'c',
                    ),
                    5 => 'baz',
                    6 => array(
                        'd' => 'd',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'foo',
                    3 => 'bar',
                    'baz' => 'baz',
                    4 => array(
                        'a',
                        1 => 'b',
                        'c',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'baz',
                    4 => array(
                        'd' => 'd',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'merge-arrays-recursively' => array(
                array(
                    'foo' => array(
                        0 => 'baz',
                        1 => 'baz',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'foo' => array(
                        'baz',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'foo' => array(
                        'baz',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'replace-string-keys' => array(
                array(
                    'foo' => 'baz',
                    'bar' => 'bat',
                ),
                array(
                    'foo' => 'bar',
                    'bar' => array(),
                ),
                array(
                    'foo' => 'baz',
                    'bar' => 'bat',
                ),
            ),
            'merge-with-null' => array(
                array(
                    'foo' => 'baz',
                    null => 'zad',
                    'cat' => 'bar',
                    'god' => null,
                ),
                array(
                    'foo' => null,
                    null => 'rod',
                    'cat' => 'bar',
                    'god' => 'rad',
                ),
                array(
                    'foo' => 'baz',
                    null => 'zad',
                    'god' => null,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try it using foreach loop?

Example jSON data 1:

```
  $json1='[
  {"PlayerID":"17794204","userName":"Vandiel","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"1476253231000"},
{"PlayerID":"21532584","userName":"Mayland","castleCount":"1","NotUpd":"0"},
{"PlayerID":"21539896","userName":"Dana","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"0"}
]';
```

Example jSON data 2:

```
$json2='[
 {"PlayerID":"17794204","Trouble":"2"},
 {"PlayerID":"21532584","Trouble":"0"},
 {"PlayerID":"21539896","Trouble":"0"}
]';
```

At first decode your fetched json data in order to convert as arrays

```
$array1=json_decode($json1,true);
$array2=json_decode($json2,true);
```

Once converted use following foreach loop in order to check 'PlayerID' is equal in both arrays. If same then merge with result array as following scripts:

```
    $result = array();

    foreach($array1 as $data1)
    {
      foreach($array2 as $data2)
      {
      if($data1['PlayerID'] == $data2['PlayerID'])
      {
        $tmp = array("Trouble" => $data2['Trouble']);
        $tmp = array_merge($data1, $tmp);
        $result[] = $tmp;

      }
    }
  }
```

Output would be merged following array exactly as wanted :

```
             array(3) {
             [0]=>
               array(5) {
               ["PlayerID"]=>
               string(8) "17794204"
               ["userName"]=>
                string(7) "Vandiel"
                ["castleCount"]=>
                string(1) "9"
                ["NotUpd"]=>
                 string(13) "1476253231000"
                ["Trouble"]=>
                string(1) "2"
                }
              [1]=>
                 array(5) {
                ["PlayerID"]=>
                string(8) "21532584"
                ["userName"]=>
                 string(7) "Mayland"
                 ["castleCount"]=>
                 string(1) "1"
                 ["NotUpd"]=>
                  string(1) "0"
                 ["Trouble"]=>
                  string(1) "0"
                 }
             [2]=>
               array(5) {
               ["PlayerID"]=>
               string(8) "21539896"
              ["userName"]=>
              string(4) "Dana"
              ["castleCount"]=>
              string(1) "9"
              ["NotUpd"]=>
              string(1) "0"
              ["Trouble"]=>
              string(1) "0"
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mergeArrays(array $arr1, array $arr2, string $idKeyName) {
        $data = [];
        foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
            $id = $value[$idKeyName];
            $data[$id] = $value;
        }

        foreach ($arr2 as $value) {
            $id = $value[$idKeyName];
            if (isset($data[$id])) {
                $data[$id] = array_merge($data[$id], $value);
            } else {
                $data[$id] = $value;
            }
        }

        return array_values($data);
    }
```

```
$arr1 = [["id" => "66395", "substanceId" => 182], ["id" => "66396", "substanceId" => 183]];
$arr2 = [["id" => "66395_new", "substanceId" => 182], ["id" => "66397", "substanceId" => 184]];
$result = mergeArrays($arr1, $arr2, 'substanceId');

# var_export($result)
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '66395_new',
    'substanceId' => 182,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '66396',
    'substanceId' => 183,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '66397',
    'substanceId' => 184,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

This PHP code should do the trick:

```
$array1 = json_decode('[
    {"PlayerID":"17794204","userName":"Vandiel","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"1476253231000"},
    {"PlayerID":"21532584","userName":"Mayland","castleCount":"1","NotUpd":"0"},
    {"PlayerID":"21539896","userName":"Dana","castleCount":"9","NotUpd":"0"}
]');
$array2 = json_decode('[
    {"PlayerID":"17794204","Trouble":"2"},
    {"PlayerID":"21532584","Trouble":"0"},
    {"PlayerID":"21539896","Trouble":"0"}
]');
$arrays_merged = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

**EDIT**

Forgot quotes around json data. Sorry, my bad, has been corrected

Comment: This too not solves his issue. Please refer to the question well. He needs to merge the arrays based on the keys. This solution will merge only the arrays.