# How to merge two JSON arrays in PHP based on a key

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

```
array1 = array(
  {'id' => '1', 'name' => 'A'},
  {'id' => '2', 'name' => 'B'},
  {'id' => '3', 'name' => 'C'},
  {'id' => '4', 'name' => 'D'}
);

array2 = array(
  {'id' => '1', 'flag' => '1'},
  {'id' => '3', 'flag' => '0'}
);
```

I need to merge them based on the 'id' key , so the result should be

```
array1 =  array(
{'id' => '1', 'name' => 'A', 'flag' => '1'},
{'id' => '2', 'name' => 'B'},
{'id' => '3', 'name' => 'C', 'flag' => '0'},
{'id' => '4', 'name' => 'D'}
);
```

any help ?

Comment: I have already answered here: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054674/php-merge-json-arrays/40054880#40054880

Comment: This question is already answered there http://stackoverflow.com/a/14843843/5788489

Comment: @NareshKumar.P I don't see JSON mentioned anywhere in [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40072805/1). Please don't edit the question unless OP explicitly mentioned that.

Comment: Here is the solution allowing you to merge two arrays according to your rule specifying the `$idKeyName` as 3rd param. It could be `id` for you, but `hash` or `timestamp` for someone else.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60605221/2263395

Answer (score 0):

```
function merge_two_arrays($array1,$array2) {
    $data = array();
    $arrayAB = array_merge($array1,$array2);
    foreach ($arrayAB as $value) {
      $id = $value['id'];
      if (!isset($data[$id])) {
        $data[$id] = array();
      }
      $data[$id] = array_merge($data[$id],$value);
    }
    return $data;
  }

$master_array = merge_two_arrays($array1,$array2);
```